# There is no "hpi/jpi" file in the 19.2.30 Fortify/Jenkins plugin; how do I install the plugin manually?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, fortify

This is the Fortify/Jenkins plugin.  We have a stand-alone Jenkins environment (not connect to the internet) and I downloaded the Fortify/Jenkins plugin from GitHub.  There doesn't appear to be any way to manually upload, since there is no .hpi/.jpi file to use.  Note:  the download was a .zip file; renaming the .zip file to .hpi didn't work either (got a "NullPointerException" in Jenkins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Fortify plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/fortify/) is available from the [GitHub releases](https://github.com/jenkinsci/fortify-plugin/releases), as well as directly from the [Jenkins updates](http://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/fortify/) Artifactory repository. The zip and tar.gz contain source files. Admittedly, the hpi is missing from the latest (19.2.30) release on GitHub, which makes me think they are not using the standard [Jenkins plugin release mechanism](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/publishing/releasing/) and something "broke". Grab it from the updates site.

You can [manually install the plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#advanced-installation) from the Plugins | Advanced page

```
Navigate to the Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins page in the web UI.
Click on the Advanced tab.
Choose the .hpi file under the Upload Plugin section.
Upload the plugin file.
```

ps: I'd suggest [clarifying your issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/fortify-plugin/issues/16) to say the **latest (19.2.30) release on GitHub is missing the hpi file**.

Comment: I just got the .hpi file (for 19.1.29); is there any particular folder I need to place this in (prior to attempting to upload it)?  This is my first time trying to implement a Jenkins plugin and I just want to make sure I'm following the proper procedure.  Many thanks.

Comment: Correction:  I believe I actually do have 19.2.30, since the Jenkins GitHub link I used has the 19.2.30 version listed.  However, the downloaded zip file was named "fortify-plugin-master-19.1", which threw me off.  However, I still need to know where to place the "hpi" file--in the folder structure (if that matters).

Comment: You use the "Upload plugin" function from the Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Advanced option. You can upload from anywhere on your HD, it does the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to upload the plugin; it's now showing up in the list of "Installed" plugins.